What would be the best way to retain or impute data containing willing OR not willing to answer?
I want to impute missing data in a survey.
In my dataset, participants could choose not to answer certain personal questions (e.g., age, family background), leading to both intentionally missing and unintentionally missing data. Given this structure, what would be the recommended imputation strategies to ensure data integrity and minimize bias?
My initial approach would involve using Little’s MCAR test on the numerical values. If the data is confirmed as MCAR, single imputation methods, EM (Expectation-Maximization) imputation, could be effective as they would introduce minimal bias. If the test suggests non-MCAR data, we could assume MAR, with MNAR being less likely based on our assumptions about the data, allowing EM imputation to remain viable.
This approach would be applicable to categorical responses as well, though the structure of the data is crucial, as some values are intentionally missing. Given this, would it be reasonable to first subdivide the data based on participants’ consent to share information and then apply imputation within these subgroups?


Example for numerical response
Q2: What is your age? {0: My age, 1: Prefer not to answer}
Q3: Open-text area (intended for age)
Thus there would be cases like

Consent and exist: Q2 (0), Q3 (22)
Consent but missing / invalid: Q2 (0), Q3 (-1)
Does not consent and does not exist: Q2 (1), Q3 (NA)
Does not consent but exist: Q2 (1), Q3 (25)

Understandably this is not the best survey structure as it does not have preventive measures. But as GDPR is prevalent, certain surveys might have this issue.

What does intentionally missing mean? E.g. in "some values are intentionally missing".

Thank you for your reply. The intentional missing values are like questions where you can skip to answer. For instance, Q2 What is your age {0: Answer, 1: Prefer not to answer}, and Q3 is an open-text area (intented for numerical age). If the respondent answer 1 (Prefer not to answer), they can skip Q3.
